# Slony-I replication CPU usage

Tags: postgresql, cpu-usage

I have recently had to install slony (version 2.0.2) at work. Everything works fine, however, my boss would like to lower the cpu usage on slave nodes during replication. Searching on the net does not reveal any blatantly obvious answers to this. Any suggestions that would help reduce CPU usage (or spread the update out over a longer period) would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into general PostgreSQL tuning here?  The server can waste a lot of CPU cycles doing redundant work if it's not given enough resources to work with, and the default config is extremely small.  [Tuning Your PostgreSQL Server](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) is a useful guide here, shared_buffers and checkpoint_segments are the two parameters you might get some significant improvement from on a slave (many of the rest only really help for improving query time).

Answer (score 1):

Magnus might be right, this could very well just be a symptom of the fact that your database has very high traffic. Slony effectively multiplies the resource usage of any given DML operation: not only is data CRUD'ed to the replication master, but every time that happens, a Slony trigger (think of it as a change listener) generates an identical transaction and forwards it to the Slon process, which runs it on other members of the cluster.

**However**, there are two other possible explanations/solutions to this issue:

1. A possible solution might be to run the slon processes on a separate machine from your database hosts. Even if you have a single-master/single-slave replication scheme, it is advantageous in terms of stability, role-segregation, and  performance (that’s you) to run the slon replication daemons on a physically different set of hardware (on the same LAN segment, ideally). There is nothing about Slony that says it has to run on the same machine as a given database host, so putting it in a different location (think “traffic controller”) might relieve some of the resource load on your database hosts. This is also a good idea in terms of both machine stability and scalability.
2. There's also a chance that this is only a temporary problem caused by the fact that you recently started using Slony. When you first subscribe a new node to a replication set, that node (and, to some extent, its parent) experiences VERY heavy CPU load (and possibly disk load as well) during the subscription process. I'm not sure how it works under the covers, but, depending on how much data was already on the node subscribed, Slony will either check the master’s data against every single piece of data present on the slave in tables that are replicated, and copy data down to the slave if it is missing or different. These are potentially CPU-intensive operations. Especially in large databases, the process of subscription can take a very long time (it took over a day for me, but our database is over 20GB), during which CPU load will be very high. A simple way to see what Slony is up to is to use [pgAdmin’s Server Status viewer](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/status.html), which, while limited, will give you some useful info here. If there are a lot of “prepare table for replication” or “cleanup table after replication” operations in progress on the node that has a high CPU load, it’s probably because a subscription isn’t complete. pgAdmin’s status viewer isn’t too informative, however; there are more reliable ways of checking subscription progress using Slony directly. Section 4.7.6.4 in the [Slony log-analysis documentation](http://slony.info/documentation/loganalysis.html) might help with that, as would reading [the doc for SUBSCRIBE SET](http://slony.info/documentation/stmtsubscribeset.html) (pay special attention to the boxed warning message, and the "Dangerous/Unintuitive Behavior" section. A simple yet definitive hack to tell whether a set is still in the process of subscriptions is to run a MERGE SET and try to merge it with an empty (or not) other set. MERGE SET will fail with a "subscriptions in progress" error if subscription is still running. However, that hack won't work on Slony 2.1; MERGE SET will just wait until subscriptions are finished.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to reduce the CPU usage would be to put less data into the database :-)

Other than that, you can experiment with *sync_interval*. It *may* be what you're looking for.

Comment: If you increase sync_interval, you might want to increase sync_group_maxsize as well; that combination should result in the server waking up less, but doing more each time, to lower overhead.

Alternately, if the idea really is to "spread the update out over a longer period", you might increase sync_interval and decrease sync_group_maxsize instead, which may result in Slony slowly trickling updates in.